# How can I improve the current enemy spawning system for my strategy game

Tags: unity, c#, game-design, rts, spawning

I'm currently making an RTS game for mobile where mini battles would take place on tiny battlegrounds.

The problem is that currently the player is spawning its units based on a currency system, whereas the enemy is spawning based on a timed system. The timed system would make sense in a tower defense game, but not here.

Here is a short clip of it in action: https://twitter.com/LewanayG/status/1378009426808950794

This is my current spawn script:

```
void Start()
    {
        //start spawning waves
        StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
    {
        //before spawning the first enemies, wait a moment
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
        while (true)
        {
            //if not all characters of this wave are spawned, spawn new enemy and that wait some time before spawning next enemy in this wave
            for (int i = 0; i < startEnemyCount; i++)
            {
                int random = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
                GameObject newEnemy = Instantiate(enemies[random], transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                newEnemy.transform.parent = enemyParent.transform;
                
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);                         // to add some randomness between spawns
            }
            
            //make sure the next wave contains more enemies than this one
            startEnemyCount += extraEnemiesPerWave;
            //wait before starting the next wave
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
        }
    }
```

Under the current system, as long as the player has more units on the battleground than the current spawn rate of the enemy it will win, and its really difficult to balance this game based on the two spawn systems.

How do you suggest I handle this problem and the spawn system of enemy units?

Comment: Why do you have those two different spawn systems in the first place? What is your design intention behind that?

Comment: @Philipp, The timed spawner was just to have something working quickly during the prototyping stage. But now as the game is developing it needs to be changed, as it can lead to snowballing and is not balanced to have a time vs currency system. To change my current system to currency I can simply replace the ``while (1)`` to ``if(enemy_currency > unit_cost)`` but that doesnt solve which unit to deploy and when? How would the game decide to deploy the cheap grunt unit or expensive tank? because under the above if condition the expensive units will never be deployed..

Comment: Well, then it seems like your actual problem is how to create an AI for your game which makes good decisions regarding how to use its resources.

Comment: I added ``ai`` to the list of tags, but it was removed and replaced by ``game-design`` by @DMGregory. And yes, that is why I posted this question in hopes of getting any ideas/solutions

Comment: You can edit the question to ask about AI decision-making instead of asking about the design of a spawning mechanic if you like. I matched the tags to the question you asked, which did not mention using an AI decision-making approach.